# Collapse of quantum state after measurement of degenerated eigenvalue (From textbook Shankar) (Closed)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, wavefunction-collapse

I want to ask an easy question from Problem 4.2.1, Quantum Mechanics(2nd) by Shankar.

Let's say Operators, $L_{x}$, $L_{y}$, $L_{z}$ are

$$L_{x}$ = $1/2^{1/2}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
 0& 1 &0 \\ 
 1&  0&1 \\ 
 0&  1& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$L_{y}$ = $1/2^{1/2}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
 0& -i &0 \\ 
 i&  0&-i \\ 
 0&  i& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$L_{z}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0& 0 \\ 
 0&  0& -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

We consider a state described as below, in the $L_{z}$ basis,

$$\mid\Psi\rangle = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
1/2\\ 
1/2\\ 
1/2^{1/2}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

If I measure $L_{z}^{2}$ and get a result +1, what would be the state of this vector?

It bugs me because it's degenerated. It should be linear combination of the two degenerate states, but the answer says

$$\frac{1}{(1/4 +1/2)^{1/2}}\left (\begin{smallmatrix}
1/2\\ 
0\\ 
1/2^{1/2}
\end{smallmatrix}\right )$$

Comment: Why “but”? What is your projection operator? What is your proposal?

Comment: I just got the answer. I skipped some part ahead of this section. The explanation was presented in some previous paragraphs.